# Automatic series/parallel configuration

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, battery-operated, configuration

I've been thinking about this issue for a while now and came here for your guided assistance.

Situation:
Ik have 4 resistors (**12V/1.25W** heater pads). I need to power them with either a 12 or 24V battery.
The problem rises when I've physically placed the resistors. I cannot change the placement nor connections of the resistors on the PCB after physically placing them. However the input voltage can and will continuously change and be **EITHER** 12 or 24 volt. nothing in between.

So my thought process was basically:
**Option1**: When powering the resistors with a **12V** battery I simply put all the resistors in parallel.
**Option2**: When powering the resistors with a **24V** battery I configure it as 2x 4 resistors in parallel.

With some help on other forums and some finetuning afterwards I came up with the following Mosfet circuit:
[image: Circuit]

**Issue:**
I'm having trouble and a hard time finding the values for the 3 mosfets. I came up with the following thought process but now I'm stuck.
-Q1 should have a VGSth of around -20V, so that when powered by a 12V battery the resistors are all in parallel.
-Q2 should have a Vgsth of around 20V. This so the current can flow to ground when 2 resistors are in series and powered by a 24V source.
Q3 should have a Vgsth of around -20V.
Keeping in mind that the battery is a Lead-Acid Battery which means that the maximum precision of the configuation will be the charged and decharged value of that battery, so about +/- delta 2V.

My problem is that If I lookup digikey I just cant find mosfet's with these parameters, where I'm I going wrong here? And is there a better way to do this with mosfets? I know one can use a relay but I want a mosfet solution.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do these "resistors" have a value? What function do they perform in this circuit? Why are there two different possible voltage supplies in use? I also notice that in one place you write "4 resistors" and elsewhere you write "2 x 3", which sounds like 6 resistors to me. So which is it?

Comment: how precisely do you need to control the resistor configuration? And related to that, what battery chemistry are you using? The Voltage vs Capacity curves will be a little different depending on the battery chemistry, thus informing the best approach

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the reply, it's 4 resistors, I've editted my mistake. Regarding the voltage supply: I'm trying to get a feeling for mosfet circuit design, so I'm trying to design a circuit that can be powered by a 12 and 24V power supply.

Comment: @LukeGary Good question regarding the prisicion of resistor configuration. It does not need to be precise. The battery will either be 12 or 24V. it's a Lead-Acid Battery and so the maximum precision of the configuation will be the charged and decharged value of that battery.

Comment: @Jr.Maxwell you still haven't answered the question what *value* these resistor have.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The resistors/heater pads have a value of 12V 1.25W. Thanks for the remark, I've editted it.

Comment: @Jr.Maxwell that is not their value. That's their power rating.

Comment: @Jr.Maxwell I'm a bit sorry, but now I'm the one to tell you that you can't design a MOSFET circuit if you don't know what the value of a resistor is; that's really the most fundamental basics of electronics, and if you don't know Ohm's law and don't know the relationship between resistance, current and voltage, then we simply can't answer your question without giving you highschool physics to basics of field effects in semiconductor devices – and that takes multiple books, not a stackexchange answer.

Comment: how are you connecting to the battery? ... if you are using a plug of some kind, then is the plug available in a 3 prong version?

Comment: This won't work as there are no FETs with Vgs(th)> 10V, and 2~4V was the old standard, but you might consider a ratio comparator or a better design

Comment: We shouldn't nitpick 1.25W/12V or ~10+ Ohms  but the Vgs(th)=Vt =20V is not possible.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yeah, I was guessing this design wasn't going to work duo to Vgs(th) limitations since I wasn't able to find Fet's on digikey with these values.  Thank you for the answer! So I have to come up with a different design, I just wanted to make it as cheap as possible haha. I'll look into ratio comparator!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thought process of design should be to define all the input and output requirements with all the ambient stress environmental specs and assumptions needed and make a list of these specs.  It should not limit the specs to any parts or configuration or imagined implementation.  Think about what is really important.

I am guessing you need to heat 4 locations evenly with 5W like a coffee cup heater and it must work off a car or truck so what counts is the temperature and not just the voltage.

Now if you define the output in terms of power instead of voltage and thermal resistance with temp rise, you can imagine PWM with a regulated thermal sensed solution.

Design Problems:

- FETS make lousy comparators due to wide variation of Vt=Vgs(th)
- Old power FETS were typically Vt= 2~4V @250uA i.e. 3V +/-33%
- They do make Vt=8.5V but never 20V . The trend now is sub-threshold FETs Vt<~1V

BTW if I guessed what you were thinking. look at Mercedes heater-cooler dual cup solution using thermal heatpump chip to make cold one side hot the other

Comment: That was what I was thinking haha, you guessed right! Thanks for the tip, I'm going to look into that. very helpful

Comment: just a lucky guess. not psychic, been there done that (ha)   But learn more about heat transfer, insulation + conduction resistance, mass. even a diode can be used as a thermometer.  Don't be cheap. then unreliable, be wiser, but then JCI probably already has a patent (hint)